# Jquery hide() , show() function is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, event-handling

i am using codeigniter bonfire for creating a web applicaion. i am using simple hide() and show() function of jquery but its not working. i will check all scripts no error on console..i cant understand why its not working.
I include jquery files are in ways :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/before.load.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/richmarker-compiled.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/smoothscroll.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/jquery.hotkeys.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/jquery.nouislider.all.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/maps.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/star-rating.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/jquery.gmap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/locationpicker.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

All files are included correctly. There is no problem to including files.
Jquery code is-:

```
<script>
function regis_form() {
    $('#is_owner').change(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#registration_fields').show();
        } else
            $('#registration_fields').hide();
    });
}
</script>
```

And at a footer i am calling regis_form(); like :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    regis_form()
});
```

Function is also calling correctly but div is not showing or hiding. Is any problem with sequence of including jquery files?

Answer (score 0):

This below snippet seems to work for me,

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script>
    function regis_form()
    {
        $('#is_owner').change(function () {
        console.log("checked"+this.checked);
        if(this.checked)
        {
           $('#registration_fields').show();
        } 
        else 
            $('#registration_fields').hide();
        });
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="is_owner" />
    <div id="registration_fields">
        <p>Content visible</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                regis_form();
            });
        </script>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function regis_form() {
  $('#is_owner').change(function() {
    console.log("checked" + this.checked);
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#registration_fields').show();
    } else
      $('#registration_fields').hide();
  });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  regis_form();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="is_owner" />
<div id="registration_fields">
  <p>Content visible</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

Function called but the problem is event not fired.

**Solution:**

1. Include jquery

   ```
    <script src="http://localhost/hungary_duniya/bonfire/themes/restaurant/assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
   ```
2. put the code in $(document).ready function

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#is_owner').click(function () {

    //console.log($(this).prop("checked));

      if($(this).prop("checked") == true){

          $('#registration_fields').show();

      }else{ 

         $('#registration_fields').hide();

      } 

    });     
   });
   ```

Hope it helps.....

Answer (score 0):

First below script put on your header file

then you will use it
Jquery('#id').hide();
or
Jquery('#id').show();